# Inserting data into user defined type in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, user-defined-types

I am having trouble inserting JSON and updating data to my Cassandra table.

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TYPE keyspace.connected_hw (
    connected_element text,
    support_list frozen<list<text>>
);

CREATE TABLE keyspace.sample_table (
    id text,
    name text,
    connected_items frozen<keyspace.connected_hw>
)
```

My insert script looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.sample_table JSON '
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "object 1",
    "connected_items": [
      {
        "connected_element": "56789",
        "support_list": ""
      }
    ]
  }

'
```

After I run this, I get the following error :

```
Error decoding JSON value for connected_items: Expected a map, but got a ArrayList :
```

I tried to insert the other fields without the 'connected_items" list first, then updating it afterwards :

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.sample_table JSON '
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "object 1",
  }

'
```

This works until I try to update 'connected_items' with

```
UPDATE keyspace.sample_table
SET connected_items = [{connected_element:'56789',support_list:['type1','type2']}] 
where id='12345'
```

After running this I get the following error :

```
InvalidQueryException: Invalid list literal for connected_items of type frozen<connected_hw>
```

Comment: What is the primary key of sample_table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `connected_items` as type `connected_hw` but you are inserting value as list of 'connected_hw ' and also `support_list` is a list of `text` not just `text`

You Either change your insert/update format like below :

```
INSERT INTO sample_table JSON '{"id": "12345", "name": "object 1", "connected_items": { "connected_element": "56789", "support_list": ["a","b"] } }' ;
```

And

```
UPDATE sample_table SET connected_items = {connected_element:'56789',support_list:['type1','type2']}  where id='12345' ;
```

Or Change the type of connected_items to list of connected_hw

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table DROP connected_items ;
ALTER TABLE sample_table ADD connected_items list<frozen <connected_hw>>;
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated my table structure and it worked fine.